# Prevent extra mouse buttons from acting as forward / back in Firefox on Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, mouse

I have a mouse with some extra buttons on it, and two of them on the side are treated as forward/back buttons by default for some reason - both in Windows and Linux. When using Windows, I can use [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to prevent these button presses from reaching Firefox, and it allows the signal to reach other programs - like Ventrilo, which is what I use it for. However, on Linux, there doesn't seem to exist any such solution. I want to be able to use this button as a PTT button without it forcing me backwards a page while I'm using Firefox. Any ideas? Also, might this button sending some kind of universal "back" signal and not just "button 8"? How could I find out?

I posted this question on reddit recently, you can see that [here.](http://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/2nljav/in_linux_is_there_any_way_of_preventing_certain/)

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1267965/598527

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel your pain. On my mouse, the accident-prone side buttons are 8 and 9 according to `xev` (4 and 5 are wheel scroll up/down). I use the following in my window manager startup script:

`xinput set-button-map '<device name of mouse>' 1 2 3 4 5 16 17 18 19`

By mapping buttons 6-9 to their original mapping + 10, they effectively become unbound to any default settings in any software that I'm aware of, but still output a usable value in case you want to deliberately enable them in software that allows custom mapping. If you just want to disable a button altogether, you can map it to zero. For more details, see `man xinput(1)`.

Comment: 3.5 years later I don't use that mouse anymore, and instead use this one with the side buttons programmed as the number pad. http://redragonusa.com/products/mice/M901/7

But that may still be a useful solution for others, thank you.

Comment: I'd still like to see a Firefox-local solution to this. It's ridiculous that Firefox lacks any option to turn this "feature" off from within the browser rather than having to remap your mouse buttons.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: https://superuser.com/a/1267965/598527