# How to disable mouse back and forward shortcuts?

Tags: firefox, mouse

Mouse's buttons 4 and 5 operate as back and forward shortcuts in Firefox. Accidentally pressing these buttons has been common with every mouse I've owned and has resulted in severe issues with banking websites and job applications. I don't want to disable the hardware keys because these extra buttons are useful especially in games with complex control schemes.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate because it's about Linux: https://superuser.com/questions/849521/prevent-extra-mouse-buttons-from-acting-as-forward-back-in-firefox-on-linux

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Type `about:config` into Firefox's address bar
2. If you haven't previously disabled it, a warning page about the dangers of changing settings that you don't understand will pop up. Read it, then click "I accept the risk!"
3. In the about:config search bar, search for `mousebutton`. You should find two preferences, `mousebutton.4th.enabled` and `mousebutton.5th.enabled`, both set to true. Double click each of these to set them to false.
4. Restart Firefox probably. IDK that's what I did, don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: Restarting Firefox wasn't necessary, or refreshing open tabs.

Comment: Is this windows only or was it added recently? I'm using 52.5.0 ESR on linux and those options don't show up.

Comment: doesn't work on firefox 58 on linux

Comment: @DuBistKomisch: @Annan: Can you try creating a new `boolean` value for both preferences in about:config?

Comment: @user598527 That's what I tried. Doesn't work. I ended up unbinding the mouse buttons somewhere in my X config.

Comment: Nothing shows up when I search for `mousebutton`.

Comment: Both preferences certainly exist on Firefox 78 and 79 stable on Linux (Fedora). I haven't used any other versions.

Comment: Just tested with Firefox 80 on Ubuntu 18.04 and it works. Thanks!

Comment: What would actually have been useful on those buttons is to cycle through tab history instead of page history. RIP

Comment: like a charm, on Firefox 106.... previously, I was using [Xmouse])(https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) running in the background 24x7 for this sole purpose, because I didn't think to check if there was a simple ff config setting (and because the problem pissed me off, *that* much!) .... but hey @Zyl -  Xmouse ***will*** let you setup custom buttons functions like page history.