# How to disable mouse back and forward shortcuts in CHROME?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, mouse

I need a way to disable the forward/back functions set automatically on mouse button 4 and 5.
I want to disable it in Chrome, but I still want it to be registered by other programs when using chrome. Thus I cannot use the software x-mouse.

Firefox has this simple trick that worked for me: [How to disable mouse back and forward shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1247367/how-to-disable-mouse-back-and-forward-shortcuts)

Now I want something for chrome.

Comment: Isn't this a feature of the mouse software, rather than the browser? (I have a Logitech MX Master 3 and this behaviour is configurable in the accompanying "Logitech Options" software.)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script you can leave running in the background to lose focus of the Chrome (or Firefox) window when Mouse3 or Mouse4 are used:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% 
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

#IfWinActive Google Chrome|Mozilla Firefox
$XButton1::
    {
    prev:=WinActive("A")
    WinActivate, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    KeyWait, XButton1
    WinActivate, ahk_id %prev%
    return
    }

#IfWinActive Google Chrome|Mozilla Firefox
$XButton2::
    {
    prev:=WinActive("A")
    WinActivate, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    KeyWait, XButton2
    WinActivate, ahk_id %prev%
    return
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ffmsb-freedom-for-mouse-s/najmjkgimjhilaleingfkhedncclmmaf) that might help to achieve this without any external crutches, I don't think there's any other way to work around this in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

To reassign a button for a specific program:

1. Using the mouse that you want to configure, start Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center.
2. Select the app-specific settings
3. Click Add New button. Select the
   program that you want
4. If the program that you want is not on the list, click Manually Add a Program at the bottom, select the program. In the button command list, select a command.

Found at [How do I reassign mouse buttons?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052294/accessories-how-do-i-reassign-mouse-buttons)

Comment: It isn't clear whether these instructions address the problem posed by the OP, but in any case these directions are only valid if you're using a microsoft mouse in windows.

Comment: Dude you just pasted the first google result. This only works for Microsoft mice!